# SQL averaging common results then only listing top 2 of those

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE CONFERENCESESSION(
SESSIONID CHAR(4),
BUILDINGNO CHAR(2),
ROOMNO CHAR(2),
SPEAKERID CHAR(2),
SESSIONDATE DATE,
SESSIONPRICE NUMBER(4, 2));

INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS01','B1','R1','S1','3-MAY-17','12.50');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS02','B2','R1','S2','4-JUNE-17','19.45');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS03','B1','R2','S2','13-MAY-17','12.67');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS04','B4','R2','S4','13-JUNE-17','14.56');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS05','B3','R2','S5','23-MAY-17','14.56');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS06','B3','R1','S5','3-JUNE-17','16.32');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS07','B4','R2','S3','13-MAY-17','21.78');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS08','B1','R2','S2','6-JUNE-17','16.82');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS09','B2','R3','S4','13-MAY-17','17.90');
INSERT INTO CONFERENCESESSION VALUES('SS10','B4','R1','S3','6-JUNE-17','16.37');

SELECT BUILDINGNO, AVG(SESSIONPRICE)
FROM  CONFERENCESESSION 
GROUP BY BUILDINGNO
ORDER BY AVG(SESSIONPRICE) DESC;
```

I have to group the conferencesession table by 'Building Numbers' then average those results. Then only printing the 2 most expensive results on the list

I thought i had to use "where rownum <= 2" somewhere but wherever I put it my code stops working or displays wrong values

Any help please?
Thanks!!

Comment: Add `FETCH FIRST 2 ROWS ONLY` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT s.BUILDINGNO,s.avg_prc
FROM(
    SELECT t.*,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.avg_prc DESC) as rnk
    FROM(
         SELECT BUILDINGNO, AVG(SESSIONPRICE) as avg_prc
         FROM  CONFERENCESESSION  
         GROUP BY BUILDINGNO) t ) s
WHERE s.rnk <= 2
```

Then you can select which one you'd like. They're ranked for biggest to smallest 1...N

Comment: what have you assigned t as?

Comment: The inner query, it's a way of habit. @jack

Comment: Sorry, I replced my existing code and came up with an error

ORA-00904: "T"."RNK": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Answer (score 0):

Perform the `GROUP` and `ORDER` in a sub-query and then restrict the rows in an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT BUILDINGNO,
         AVG(SESSIONPRICE) as avg_prc
  FROM   CONFERENCESESSION  
  GROUP BY BUILDINGNO
  ORDER BY avg_prc DESC
)
WHERE  ROWNUM <= 2;
```

Also note: `'3-MAY-17'` is not a date - it is a String literal and Oracle will try to perform an implicit conversion using `TO_DATE( value, format_model, nlsparams )` using the current user's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model (and other NLS settings for the third argument).

You need to be aware that these are set in the user session and can be modified by each user so your query can break without changing the text of the query if the user alters those parameters.

It is better to get into the habit of using date literals `DATE '2017-05-03'` or explicitly performing the conversion with all the parameters `TO_DATE( '3-MAY-17', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=''ENGLISH''' )` rather than relying on implicit conversion.